# singleTask app doesn't reuse the Task already present in recent apps when started with startActivityForResult method

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode, share-intent

I have two android apps, lets call them app A and app B.
Inside app A I create a share intent as follows:
`shareIntent=Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null); // sendIntent contains data to share.`
this will be used to pass data to app B.
App B's MainActivity (its only Activity) is configured to have `launchMode="singleTask"`.

**Behavior 1**:
If from app A I use `startActivity(shareIntent)` and app B was in background, it comes to foreground and handles the intent with onNewIntent method. If app B wasn't in background it starts a new task for app B with its initial intent set to sendIntent that was passed from app A.

**Behavior 2**:
If from app A I use `startActivityForResult(shareIntent, SUCCESS_CODE)` it doesn't matter if app B was in background or not, It is started afresh, moreover the `MainActivity` of app B is started and pushed to the backStack of app A, it doesn't start in a separate task, after this I have 2 MainActivities of app B, one which I kept in background, and one launched inside app A.

Why does `startActivityForResult` causes Behavior 2?
What can be done as a developer of app B who has no control over how app A starts it to always show Behavior 1?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot start an `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()` if that `Activity` has launch mode of `singleTask` or `singleInstance`. The reason is that `startActivityForResult()` requires the target `Activity` (i: the one being launched) to run in the **same task as the `Activity` that expects the result**.

Normally, if you try to launch an `Activity` and that `Activity` is declared with launch mode of `singleTask` or `singleInstance`, Android automatically adds `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent` and ensures that the target `Activity` is launched in a separate task.

If a developer expects that his `Activity` will be launched using `startActivityForResult()` and he codes the `Activity` to actually return a result, it makes absolutely no sense to declare this `Activity` with launch mode of `singleTask` or `singleInstance`.

This behaviour is not what you say you are seeing, but it is clear that there is a conflict between the contract for `startActivityForResult()` and launch mode of `singleTask`.